# Queing and Map/Reduce

Tags: hadoop, priority-queue

Ive seen big data queuing jobs that are performant for real time work because they produce data that is readily consumed.  Map/Reduce jobs (hadoop) are performant for a different reason : they are offline and allow massively parallel data joins and aggregations.

**However, I wonder - are any systems for large data ingestion capable of implementing map/reduce style parallelism in conjunction with real time data feeds ?**

Concretely, this would mean (in hadoop), allowing for the reading and writing and aggreation of "partial" output files which were not yet complete.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [HStreaming](http://www.hstreaming.com/technology/hstreaming/) which user MR paradigm. I haven't used them, so I don't know the pros and cons.

> Common code base and tooling for real-time and batch processing.
>
> HStreaming enables to use the same MapReduce and Apache Pig algorithms and functions for real-time or batch processing. Existing code such as user-defined functions (UDF) can be migrated to stream processing with no or minimal changenot to changing business requirements.

If not MR, then there are [S4](http://incubator.apache.org/s4/), [Storm](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm) (called Hadoop of real time processing), [StreamBase](http://www.streambase.com/company/), [HPCC](http://hpccsystems.com/) and other options for real time processing.

Comment: Thanks again.  I wonder how you know so much about the software around the hadoop ecosystem.